# Creating Subset Datasets in R based on distinct field values

Tags: sql, r, subset, distinct

I am trying to split a dataset into multiple subsets based on distinct field values. For example:

```
SaleID Country
Sale1 US
Sale2 Mexico
Sale3 US
Sale4 Canada
Sale5 Canada
Sale6 Mexico
Sale7 Canada
```

Desired output (3 subsets)

```
Data 1
SaleID Country
Sale1 US
Sale3 US

Data 2
SaleID Country
Sale2 Mexico
Sale6 Mexico


Data 3
Sale4 Canada
Sale5 Canada
Sale7 Canada
```

Any ideas? My actual dataset has close to 100 distinct countries. I have explored using the sqldf package in R but no luck yet. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to create a list `L` of those data sets.  Then you can refer to `L$US` or `L[["US"]]`, say, and refer to all the names using `names(L)`.

```
L <- split(DF, DF$Country)
```

It would be possible to copy them to individual data frames in the global environment using the following line but it is not really recommended:

```
list2env(L, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `split` from `base R` to a `list` of `data.frame`s.  The order of the datasets seems to be order in which the `unique` values appear in the 'Country'.  In that case, we can convert the 'Country' to a `factor` column with `levels` specified

```
df$Country <- factor(df$Country, levels = unique(df$Country))
lst <- lapply(split(df, df$Country), `row.names<-`, NULL)
names(lst) <- paste0("Data", seq_along(lst))
```

It is better to use the `list` for processing the data instead of having multiple objects.  But, if we really need it, then `list2env`

```
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
Data1
#  SaleID Country
#1  Sale1      US
#2  Sale3      US

Data2
#  SaleID Country
#1  Sale2  Mexico
#2  Sale6  Mexico

Data3
#  SaleID Country
#1  Sale4  Canada
#2  Sale5  Canada
#3  Sale7  Canada
```